# display other text in datagridview cells

Tags: c#, winforms

I have datagridview1 and set `datagridview1.Rows.Insert(0, "name");`
now I want `datagridview1.value=name` but show text=other text.

I want `datagridview1` show for example name22 instead name but `datagridview1` value only recognize name instead name22

Comment: can have a look at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/11fd0594-48ee-4f7f-b895-192a9d3a9f1e/

Answer (score 0):

Well struggled to understand your question but I suppose you could do this:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow grid1row in Datagridview1.Rows)
{
    if(grid1row.Cells["field name"].Value.Equals("name"))
    {
        grid1row.Cells["field name"].value = other text;
    }
}
```

Is this what you mean?